# Navigation Buttons (Back, Home, Menu, etc.) in the Notification/Statusbar?

Tags: notifications, buttons, notification-bar

I am remotely controlling an old Nexus One attached and talking to a Lego NXT robot. The Nexus One has a broken Home button. In the past I remember overcoming that by finding an app which added an emulated Home button placed in the Android notification/status bar pulldown.

The Nexus One is running CM7, I am controlling it by pushing/running scripts (ssh and http/https servers) and full GUI control (VNC server). Even with all of that control, I am still missing basic button/navigation control.

Any ideas on how to overcome this? I once used an OSD trackball emulator. Anyone know of OSD buttons or recall what I may have used to get a Home button in my notification menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be talking about [Button Savior](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smart.swkey), but even if not, this APP allows you to trigger click on your phone buttons:

> **Relevant Features with or without root**
>
> Simulates:
>
> - Home key
> - Power key
> - Volume key
> - Camera key
> - Call key

[image: Button Savior Screen Shot]

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing, I was completely unaware of this app. Works as expected.